# how to get string from different locales in Android?

Tags: android, locale, android-resources

So I want to get the value of a String in several locales regardless of the current locale setting of the device/app. How should I do that?

Basically what I need is a function `getString(int id, String locale)` rather than `getString(int id)`

How could I do that?

Thanks

Comment: how did you actually implement this ?? Please do reply :)

Comment: are `ResourceBundle` supposed to refer to assets ?? or can they access our res folder ?

Comment: You need to specify another language than the usual ? If you work with different languages resources, when you do `getString(R.strings.text)` you will get the string in the users language (or the default if the users language is don't have a folder)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

**NOTE** If your minimum API is 17+, go straight to the bottom of this answer. Otherwise, read on...

**NOTE** If you are using App Bundles, you need to make sure you either disable language splitting or install the different language dynamically. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51054393 for this. If you don't do this, it will always use the fallback.

If you have various res folders for different locales, you can do something like this:

```
Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("pl");
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
Resources resources = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, conf);
String str = resources.getString(id);
```

Alternatively, you can just restart your activity using the method pointed to by @jyotiprakash.

**NOTE** Calling the `Resources` constructor like this changes something internally in Android. You will have to invoke the constructor with your original locale to get things back the way they were.

**EDIT** A slightly different (and somewhat cleaner) recipe for retrieving resources from a specific locale is:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
Locale savedLocale = conf.locale;
conf.locale = desiredLocale; // whatever you want here
res.updateConfiguration(conf, null); // second arg null means don't change

// retrieve resources from desired locale
String str = res.getString(id);

// restore original locale
conf.locale = savedLocale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);
```

As of API level 17, you should use `conf.setLocale()` instead of directly setting `conf.locale`. This will correctly update the configuration's layout direction if you happen to be switching between right-to-left and left-to-right locales. (Layout direction was introduced in 17.)

There's no point in creating a new `Configuration` object (as @Nulano suggests in a comment) because calling `updateConfiguration` is going to change the original configuration obtained by calling `res.getConfiguration()`.

I would hesitate to bundle this up into a `getString(int id, String locale)` method if you're going to be loading several string resources for a locale. Changing locales (using either recipe) calls for the framework to do a lot of work rebinding all the resources. It's much better to update locales once, retrieve everything you need, and then set the locale back.

**EDIT** (Thanks to @Mygod):

If your minimum API level is 17+, there's a much better approach, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629163/535871) on another thread. For instance, you can create multiple `Resource` objects, one for each locale you need, with:

```
@NonNull Resources getLocalizedResources(Context context, Locale desiredLocale) {
    Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf = new Configuration(conf);
    conf.setLocale(desiredLocale);
    Context localizedContext = context.createConfigurationContext(conf);
    return localizedContext.getResources();
}
```

Then just retrieve the resources you like from the localized `Resource` object returned by this method. There's no need to reset anything once you've retrieved the resources.

Comment: Shouldn't you make a new configuration from the one returned by `getResources().getConfiguration()`? According to GrepCode, it returns a local instance stored within the Resources. Changing the locale field afterwards is probably the true reason Android is confused. You should probably do `conf = new Configuration(conf);` (to clone the returned Configuration) between the first and second line.

Comment: @Nulano - It's worth trying, but I don't think that's the source of why Android is "confused" (as you put it). Look at the source for the `Resources` constructor and you'll see that creating a new `Resources` object like this changes things deep in the process's assets (apparently a singleton). Once I realized that things would need to be reset, I didn't bother tracking down exactly why. An alternative (perhaps cleaner) approach to constructing a new `Resources` object is to call `resources.updateConfiguration(conf, null)` after changing locales.

Comment: There's a better API in API level 17+: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33629163/2245107

Comment: @Mygod - Yes, that does seem like the right way to go. I'll update my answer to indicate that. Thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer with a note about app bundles breaking this functionality per default, as with bundles the user will only receive one language. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51054393 on how to fix this.

Answer (score 38):

Here is a combined version of the approaches described by [Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475663/1665966). This way, the code works for any Android version:

```
public static String getLocaleStringResource(Locale requestedLocale, int resourceId, Context context) {
    String result;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) { // use latest api
        Configuration config = new Configuration(context.getResources().getConfiguration());
        config.setLocale(requestedLocale);
        result = context.createConfigurationContext(config).getText(resourceId).toString();
    }
    else { // support older android versions
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration conf = resources.getConfiguration();
        Locale savedLocale = conf.locale;
        conf.locale = requestedLocale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(conf, null);

        // retrieve resources from desired locale
        result = resources.getString(resourceId);

        // restore original locale
        conf.locale = savedLocale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(conf, null);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage example:

```
String englishName = getLocaleStringResource(new Locale("en"), R.string.name, context);
```

*Note*

As already stated in the original answer, it might be more efficient to replace multiple call of the above code with a single configuration change and multiple resources.getString() calls.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the above answers which awesome but a little complex.
try this simple function:

```
public String getResStringLanguage(int id, String lang){
    //Get default locale to back it
    Resources res = getResources();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    Locale savedLocale = conf.locale;
    //Retrieve resources from desired locale
    Configuration confAr = getResources().getConfiguration();
    confAr.locale = new Locale(lang);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    Resources resources = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, confAr);
    //Get string which you want
    String string = resources.getString(id);
    //Restore default locale
    conf.locale = savedLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);
    //return the string that you want
    return string;
}
```

Then simply call it: `String str = getResStringLanguage(R.string.any_string, "en");`

Happy code :)

Answer (score 4):

place this Kotlin extension function into your code and use it like this:

getLocaleStringResource(Locale.ENGLISH,R.string.app_name)

```
fun Context.getLocaleStringResource(
requestedLocale: Locale?,
resourceId: Int,
): String {
val result: String
val config =
    Configuration(resources.configuration)
config.setLocale(requestedLocale)
result = createConfigurationContext(config).getText(resourceId).toString()

return result
}
```

Comment: Nice clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

### SOLUTION 2023:

Slightly modified solution: ***Usama Saeed US***

---

```
class LanguageUtil(private val activity: MainActivity) {

    companion object {
        var locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()
    }

    fun getStringResource(
        resourceId: Int,
        locale: Locale = LanguageUtil.locale,
    ): String = with(activity) { Configuration(resources.configuration).run {
        setLocale(locale)
        createConfigurationContext(this).getString(resourceId)
    } }

}
```

---

PS. Vel_daN: Love what You DO .

Answer (score 0):

Could this be done by for example?

```
String stringFormat = getString(stringId);
String string = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, stringFormat, 6);
```

Comment: The question is not about formatting a string but about getting a string from a different string.xml file without changing the phone localization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension function to get your string locale

```
fun Context.getLocaleStringResource(
localeName: String,
resourceId: Int,
): String {
    val config = Configuration(resources.configuration)
    config.setLocale(Locale(localeName))

    return createConfigurationContext(config).getText(resourceId).toString()
}
```

Then call it:

```
getLocaleStringResource("en", R.string.app_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

### I created those two extensions functions for kotlin:

```kotlin
fun Context.getString(locale: Locale, @StringRes resId: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any): String {
    var conf: Configuration = resources.configuration
    conf = Configuration(conf)
    conf.setLocale(locale)
    val localizedContext = createConfigurationContext(conf)
    return localizedContext.resources.getString(resId, *formatArgs)
}

fun Context.getString(locale: Locale, @StringRes resId: Int): String {
    var conf: Configuration = resources.configuration
    conf = Configuration(conf)
    conf.setLocale(locale)
    val localizedContext = createConfigurationContext(conf)
    return localizedContext.resources.getString(resId)
}
```

---

And you can use it like this:

```kotlin
getString(Locale("PT"), R.string.some_string, foo, bar)
getString(Locale.FRANCE, R.string.some_other_string)
```