# App language changes on its own on making a call for dfp ads in android N

Tags: android, webview, google-dfp, android-7.0-nougat

I have an app which support two language english and indonesian(bahasa).

I am facing an issue in android N.

I am using dfp sdk to show native ads to our user, everything works great as long as I am in my english layout but as soon as I change my app language to indonesian and make a request for ads, my app language forcefully changes to english and the layout breaks.

The app works fine if I dont make any call to dfp.

Has anyone else faced this issue before?

I think my problem is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398528/android-webview-locale-changes-abruptly-on-android-n). I am following the solutions provided here but no luck so far :(. Can any one help me with this.

Comment: Please provide more details with code. How are you displaying the ads, for instance: in a WebView Activity or a WebView inside an Activity with other native components?

Comment: I am displaying my ads in simple View in android. I am not using any webview. I have a recycler view and in those I am rendering the ad. But when I call DFP for ads the app locale abrubtly changes. Do you need code sample now?