# LayoutInflater.inflate changes locale in app

Tags: android, android-fragments, locale

I have an app that sets the `locale` based on user input. This is working fine for all views except one `fragment`.

During:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (rootView == null) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booking, container, false);
```

It changes the `locale`... If I debug, before the inflate-line the `getResources().getConfiguration().locale` is the `locale` the user has selected. But after this line, the same value has changed to the Phone Device's `locale`... This is not happening in other fragments even though it's written exactly the same way.

This is the code that sets the locale:

```
public static void setApplicationLanguage(Context context) {
    try {
        String languageCode = StorageManager.getInstance().getStringValue(MarketRegions.SELECTED_LANGUAGE, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);
        Locale locale = new Locale(StringUtils.substring(languageCode, 0, 2), StringUtils.substring(languageCode, 3, 5));

        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = resources.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = locale;

        resources.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it a bug in Android?

I can give more info if needed. Thanks! :)

Comment: Please show the code where you are setting user locale.

Comment: @SachinAggarwal Done

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398528/android-webview-language-changes-abruptly-on-android-n