# Using a webview changed default language

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-webview

My app default language is Spanish (es). I have introduced a webview in XML. Prior to this change, the language is Spanish. After adding the webview, it's automatically showing English. How can I fix this issue or problem?

Thanks for helping in advance.
I already used below code too.

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setUserAgentString(String.valueOf(Locale.SPANISH));
```

```
<WebView
   android:id="@+id/webView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
   tools:ignore="WebViewLayout" />
```

Comment: Please look into that: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398528/android-webview-language-changes-abruptly-on-android-7-0-and-above

Comment: Edited to use better code blocks, and cleaned up grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically add web view and initialize the language again after that.

```
    llDynemic=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.test);

    WebView webView = new WebView(getContext());// webview in mainactivity
            webView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<style>img{display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%;} a {color: #337ab7;}</style>" + newBody, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
            llDynemic.addView(webView);

// initialize the language here
```

and it will work

Comment: **Thanks @Ajaya Tiwari**, You save my day, it's working fine thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

in activity have webView

```
 @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    init here language again  then 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_terms_of_use);
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing and following the advices from the other answers, I've finally fixed the issue.

**Issues with `WebView`:**

- `WebView` have to be loaded dynamically in the activity. Loading from XML file via `Activity#setContentView()` won't work for the first time and localisation of the entire activity will break. However, subsequent launches or `Activity#recreate()` will work as expected.
- Even if `WebView` is loaded dynamically, it won't work for the first time. Again, subsequent launches or `Activity#recreate()` will work properly.

Considering the issues above, the solution involves loading `WebView` dynamically and then, the immediate recreation of the activity.

**ActivityWithWebView.java**

```java
public class ActivityWithWebView extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private static boolean firstTime = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_web_view);
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) actionBar.setTitle(R.string.instructions);
        // WebView has to be loaded dynamically to prevent in-app localisation issue.
        webView = new WebView(this);
        if (firstTime) {
            // Recreate if loaded for the first time to prevent localisation issue.
            recreate();
            firstTime = false;
            return;
        }
        LinearLayoutCompat webviewWrapper = findViewById(R.id.webview_wrapper);
        webView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        webviewWrapper.addView(webView);
        // Do other works.
    }
}
```

**activity_with_web_view.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?android:colorBackground" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/webview_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jetpack composes' Accompanist WebView same thing will happen, the same way I solved it was to set the language again in the param

```
WebView(
      onCreated = { //here set the language again }
)
```

hope this will help someone.