# Not Able to Change Webview Language

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, locale

I have a Webview in my Activity and everytime whichever site i open it loads the site in an indian language whereas i always want the user to choose language or atleast set the default language to English

Tried

```
setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);


public void setLocale(Locale locale){
    Resources resources = getApplicationContext().getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
            resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

And

```
Locale.setDefault(...);

Locale.getDefault(...);
```

I even tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/40675539/12004834 this answer but the sites are still loading in other languages.

Comment: I think it's helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398528/android-webview-language-changes-abruptly-on-android-7-0-and-above

Comment: Tried them all. None Helped @NensiKasundra

Comment: ok i will check

Comment: Try this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself