# How to debug android application localization?

Tags: android, localization

I have an old android application I inherited.  It has strings files in multiple locales (e.g., es, fr, pt).  I'm pretty sure localization used to work .. or still works?

Here's what I did:

- run an android emulator (the "qemu-system-i386" with Orange Rise 32 API version 23, which is android 6.0, to test older hardware)
- run the app in Android Studio and it gets deployed to the emulator
- set the locale.  I tried 1) using the "Settings" in the emulator, 2) Tried through `adb shell` as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization).

It looks to me like the localization settings are changed in the emulator.  All the controls and menus for the system are in Spanish, for example.

When I look at the app, it's all still default resources.  I can stop and restart the app in Android Studio, and it's still all default resources.  I added a "current_locale" string in each strings file ("default" in default, "es" in the es version, etc.), and display it.  It shows "default".

I can't get the locale from Java, since that requires minSdkVersion 28, and I'm trying to support back to version 14.

Nothing useful in the logcat window.

How can I tell what's going on?

I guess I could deploy it to a phone somehow and see if it works there.

Comment: Maybe try to recreate string files. They could be created in the wrong way or not compatible if there were any changes lately. Follow this documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization#creating-alternatives

Also, there is a bug with WebViews I had in my app. If your app is using WebView somehow it just resets your locale to default after WebView is used. I don't know if this got fixed but I ran into this problem earlier this year and read it was really a bug a lot of people had.

Comment: Thank you! I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/40675539 is describing this. I will try it.

Comment: I (re?)-discovered that this app has a "Settings" screen that allows you to override the language. So it was internal. However, your comment helped me find that, so thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad to help.