# Load default value of string programmatically

Tags: android, localization

I have got in my `strings.xml` a string with translations:

```
default: <string name="help">Help</string>
values-de: <string name="help">Hilfe</string>
values-it: <string name="help">Aiuto</string>
```

let's say my device is in Italian. My string will look like

> Aiuto

let's say I've got a `Button` below the `TextView` where "Aiuto" is displayed.

When I press the button I need the string to reset to it's default value, so in this case from

> "Aiuto" to "Help"

Is there any way I can do this programatically?

Comment: you need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475589/how-to-get-string-from-different-locales-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Locale programmatically using the [`Locale.setDefault()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault(java.util.Locale)).

Note that the Locale will reset on configuration change. 
Refer this post on how to handle that: 
[Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4239680/3857465)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get it, but I don't need to change the whole app locale. I just some strings to be in English not all of them

Comment: @Daniele Then this answer should definitely help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475663/3857465