# How to get other language string value in android?

Tags: android, android-xml

I am using English and German language in app.

When an app is in German I need to get the English value for the string which is stored in both German and English.

**English String file:**

```
<string name="good">Good</string>
```

**German String file:**

```
<string name="good">Gut</string>
```

When I use this below code when an app running in German, It is returning "Gut" but how to get forcefully English value "Good"?

```
String value = getString(R.string.good);
```

Comment: keep separate untranslated strings variables for this purpose in both the language strings.xml file.

Comment: I found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145807/2599596 thank for picking right link @Nilesh Rathod

Comment: @NaveenKumarM welcome happy to hear that