# Android: Get the list of languages my application is localized

Tags: android, locale

My application is localized in 23 languages. I want to get this list programmatically without hard coding it again.

eg: en, ar, es, he, iw, de, da

Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475589/how-to-get-string-from-different-locales-in-android

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It is for getting a string in a locale different that apps's locale. What I am looking for is, list of languages or locales app is localized. eg: en, ar, es, he, iw, de, da