# Android how to identify the string is present in string.xml file?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How to identify one string is present into string.xml file for one locale and not for other locale?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475589/how-to-get-string-from-different-locales-in-android

Comment: If you're looking for missing translations you could try the Translations Editor in Android Studio (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor#correct)

Answer (score 0):

From directory-tree expand the "values" folder and right click on the strings.xml.
Open Translator Editor. From there you can check all of your strings and their translations in different languages.