# priority in res folder in android?

Tags: android

I have made a project in which I am using different language's xml,like `language_hi.xml`,`language_en.xml`. so according to documentation I have made different folder for my each xml. For example for *language_hi.xml* I have made `es/values-hi` for *language_en* I have made *res/values-en* and in my each xml the string name is same,is there any way to select *language_en.xml* on one button click and *language_hi.xml* on another event.

this is my xml

**res/values-hi/language_hi.xml**

```
<string name="hello">sachit</string>

<string name="app">colon</string>
```

**res/values-en/language_en.xml**

```
<string name="hello">astro</string>

<string name="app">dev</string>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to change the language under which the app runs, or do you want to pick specific strings from each XML?

Comment: for example i am doing this
String s1=getResources().getString(R.string.hello);
so at this stage what will be in s1 'sachit' or 'astro' because string name hello exists in both xml's. so is there any way to select the desire string from desire xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the `Locale` to use at runtime; for example, setting it to English will result in the values from the `res\values-en\...` folder being used.

To do this, the following code is necessary:

```
Resources res = getResources(); // From your context
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("en"); // For English
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm); // Now, update the language
```

**However**, I strongly recommend against using this. When a user runs an app, they expect it to either be in the default language (which in many cases is English), or their localized language. Giving someone an app in Hindi, for example, when they are in Russia, is really no good.

Keep in mind, that if you are using `en` for your entire app, getting a value from `languages_hi.xml` is incredibly difficult and, really, should not be done in any situation. An application should be the same language throughout, or it will begin to confuse the user (with the exception of apps that handle translations between languages). However, if you are interested in doing this (for whatever esoteric reason), you should review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6526588/1438733).

PS: I assume you know this, but I should mention it anyway. Any strings in the `res\values\...` folder are used if the locale which the phone uses is not specified using `res\values-xx\...`. You can find information on this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. Android decides language according to device's language on runtime. You can force to change device's language but it is not a well solution. Instead you can produce your own solution, and you can change every string by yourself.For instance, you can put language option to your preference. then according to chosen language you can show strings of that language. suppose you have a message like "please enter password". you can write a method getStringAccordingToLanguage("password_warning"). This method will return "please enter password" if the language is in English. you can put this method in place of strings.

Comment: In my experience forcing the locale on an application won't work for more than one activity at a time. You'll either have to force it on every `onCreate` or correctly fill your string file and request the user to change the language of the tablet