# Android is taking wrong layout on Inflating View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have layouts inside 3 folders:

layout

layout-large

layout-xlarge

When I start root activity everything is fine and android is inflating view from layout-xlarge folder (I' m using Samsung tablet that belongs to xlarge device)
When I start next activity android is for some reason takign xml file from layout folder. I already tried obvious things like checking dimensions inside xml files, setting support small, normal, large and xlarge screens inside my Manifest file.

There is a interesting thing that if I before starting activity write this code android 'll take xml file from x-large folder, but this looks silly  (since android have his own logic of getting xml files from different layout fodlers)

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
            DisplayMetrics mDispMetrics = .getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            getResources().updateConfiguration(config, mDispMetrics);
```

What could be a problem?

I'm using Android 3.0 api-11

here is normal layout sample_normal.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llAssetMainWrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvSample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is corresponding row_sample_normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flRowVOD"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/iconEmpty"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#434343"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    </View>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is xlarge:
sample_xlarge.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llAssetMainWrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvSample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is corresponding row_sample_xlarge.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flRowVOD"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/iconEmpty"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#434343"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    </View>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 take layout from layout-xhdpi if this not there then it will look for large. check whether you have the xml for the next activity placed under layout-large-xhdpi andlayout-xlarge-xhdpi or not.

Comment: I tried but same thing is happening, he's constantly getting layout from layout folder not even layout-large

Comment: have layouts like this 
layout-large-xhdpi, layout-xlarge-xhdpi instead of
layout-large,layout-xlarge

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone stumbles on same problem:

I had issue using class UrlImageViewHelper that was probably downloaded from github (nos sure anymore). Class is used to download and hash images. There was code:

```
    if (mMetrics != null)
        return;
    mMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    Activity act = (Activity) context;
    act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mMetrics);
    AssetManager mgr = context.getAssets();
    mResources = new Resources(mgr, mMetrics, null);
```

By this you'll corrupt your resources (obviously)

Answer (score 0):

If your large corresponds to ~7 inch tablets, xlarge corresponds to ~10 inch tablets, it is more appropriate to use the qualifiers -sw600dp and -sw720dp respectively.

Comment: What are the differences between your 3 different layouts? Please post the code.

Comment: You seem to be trying programmatically to find the optimized layout required for the device in consideration. Try leaving it to Android resource system and for that you would need to have the layout file names to be same in all folders for a particular activity.

Comment: names are the same I just postet here names as samples, originally they are called same at different folders
layout:
assets.xml
row_assets.xml

layout-xlarge:
assets.xml
row_assets.xml

Comment: check this app to be sure about the device display. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo&hl=en

Comment: cool app, thanks, it's a XLarge MDPI device widht 1280, Height: 752.