# how i can get title of menuitem in french string resource while the current locale is english?

Tags: android, android-layout, menuitem, android-resources

how i can get title of menuitem in french string resource while the current locale is english ?

I want in special case only always get title in french ,, for ex. to send it with request...

*menuItem.getTitle().toString()    ---> only get string from current local*

Comment: Look at this [closely related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771531/android-how-to-get-string-in-specific-locale-without-changing-the-current-local) - it looks like something you can try out for your specific use case.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla  its not related to menuitem title ,, the deffirence i dont know title string name resource

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it as below:

`Resources res = getResources();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
Locale savedLocale = conf.locale; // save your current local;
conf.locale = new Local("fr"); // new french local config
res.updateConfiguration(conf, null); // update your config to french.
// retrieve resources from desired locale
String str = res.getString(id);
// restore original locale
conf.locale = savedLocale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);`

Answer (score 0):

i use

android:titleCondensed

to set value !