# is it possible to pass the localization with getString - Android

Tags: java, android

There's an instance where I want to specify a spanish version of the copy.  Even though the default language is set to english.

Is it possible to pass the localization-specified for getString()?

Comment: it seems like there's no good straightforward way to do that. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771531/android-how-to-get-string-in-specific-locale-without-changing-the-current-local for workarounds

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a string from a different locale, then you'll need to temporarily switch the locale. You can find the example here: [how to get string from different locales in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475589/how-to-get-string-from-different-locales-in-android)