# how do you translate your toast?

Tags: java, android, android-toast

hi my toast needs to translate to France or English depending on what you select as your language, in the login screen you can select your languages

Comment: if you use JS to show toast, then show how you do that.

Comment: You'll need to connect to Google Translate.

Answer (score 1):

Put your texts for the default language in res/values/strings.xml .
and create res/values-fr/strings.xml where you put the translations for french and repeat for each language.

Your application will be shown in the correct language depending in the phone language setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different string resource file based on country. Then android will automatically refer the message from proper string file based on the selected language.

Answer (score 0):

Create strings.xml file depends on language.
Read: 
[stackoverflow.com/a/41907754/1636478](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41907754/1636478) 
[Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)