# How getResources().getString() works android

Tags: android, string, locale, multilingual, android-resources

For e.g there is app which provides multi-language support, in my activity/UI, I call `getResources().getString(R.string.hello)` which exist in strings.xml,such that

```
values\strings.xml
values-ru\strings.xml
```

Now when calling `getResources().getString(R.string.hello)` and need to access string based on system locale, so will one get strings from `values\strings.xml` OR `values-ru\strings.xml`?

OR

does one need to change my app locale based on system locale (keep app locale same as system locale) and then retrieve the value from `getString()`, something suggested in below links

1. [get-string-from-default-locale-using-string-in-specific-locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6526588/1225413)
2. [how-to-get-string-from-different-locales-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475663/1225413)

I have searched various other links, but not able to find the solution

Comment: based on system locale, you will get from values\strings.xml file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

Add the string values for each locale into the appropriate file.

**At runtime, the Android system uses the appropriate set of string resources based on the locale currently set for the user's device.**

For info on Localizing with Resources

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

More info @

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Also check the below link

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java/

```
86     @Override
87     public Resources getResources()
88     {
89         return mBase.getResources();
90     }
```

Return a Resources instance for your application's package.

```
332 
333     public final String getString(int resId) {
334         return getResources().getString(resId);
335     }
```

Return a localized string from the application's package's default string table.
Parameters:
resId Resource id for the string

Comment: thanks, for long description, actually i did look into but was not able to understand.

Comment: @AkhilJain glad if i could help. I think doc has all the info you need. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html. What part did you not understand?

Comment: i opened the grep code for the Resources class, but was not able to understand as the code seemed scattered at first glance, spending more time seemed digging hole more deeper

Comment: Does getString get the string from memory or from disk? Trying to understand what the latency in getString is.

Answer (score 2):

It is done automatically. By standard the language that is on is in your `values\strings.xml` but if the user device has his language set to ru the string automatically is the one on the `values-ru\strings.xml` and so on for all the languages that you put on your resources.

You can read more about this subject in [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

> At runtime, the Android system uses the appropriate set of string resources based on the locale currently set for the user's device.