# Getting IndexOutOfBound exception during setting a text to TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, indexoutofboundsexception

My application is working well in my test device and also to most of the users (maybe), but I am getting a crash report in my play console account and I don't understand where the problem is. I am attaching a screenshot of the stack traces and the codes.

This is line no. 60, AdhynikYugDetails.java, as mentioned in stack traces:

```
tv_detailed_description.setText(R.string.jatiyatabadi_andolan_details);
```

There are many lines like this, but only this line is responsible for  the crash: [Stack traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAOU8.jpg)

This is the full block:

```
else if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("jatiyatabadi_andolan", AdhunikYug.jatiyatabadi_andolan)) {
        tv_heading.setText(R.string.jatiyatabadi_andolan);
        tv_detailed_description.setText(R.string.jatiyatabadi_andolan_details); //line no 60

        AdhunikYug.jatiyatabadi_andolan = false;
    }
```

Could there be a problem in the string? should I post it? It is a long Bengali string.

Comment: How long is this string?

Comment: Its a short question answer type string, and there are 245 questions and there answers

Answer (score 1):

Do this:-

```
tv_detailed_description.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.jatiyatabadi_andolan_details));
```

Comment: Thank you @Raj for your response. could you please explain it? The application is working very well in my test device, Lenovo K3 Note and may be to most of the users.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641994/how-getresources-getstring-works-android

Comment: Thanks again @Raj, I was saying that my application was working well from the beginning. I will surely accept your answer if the problem gets solved. Is there a way to check it right now, without uploading a new version? Sorry for the delay.

Comment: It's fairly simple: what you were doing is setting a string `Resource` as a text. It may work on some devices, but more bullet-proof way would be to do as @Raj said, by extracting that resource via android tools and passing in to `setText` method as `String` instead

Comment: @Raj the method setText() has 6 implementations: `public final void setText(CharSequence text)`,  
`public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type)`   
`private void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type, boolean notifyBefore, int oldlen)`
`public final void setText(char[] text, int start, int len)`
`public final void setText(@StringRes int resid)`
`public final void setText(@StringRes int resid, BufferType type)`