# Android localization independent from phone language settings

Tags: android, localization

I have a bunch of localized `strings.xml` files as good located in `values-XX` folders.
Definetely, I know how to localize my app dependently from phone language settings. It is easy, right? Just change phone language settings, and Android will take`strings.xml` linked to picked language.
In my case I should to allow to user pick preferable language, in application settings.

So, I want to know. Is it possible to keep my current `R.string.<anything>` everywhere, is it possible to say to Android : "hey! I need to use `strings.xml` from `values-EN` folder (for example)?"

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475589/how-to-get-string-from-different-locales-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526201/get-string-from-default-locale-using-string-in-specific-locale